# coldfusion.util.Key Memory Leak - Issue with Structure Keys?

Tags: memory-leaks, coldfusion

Consistently, I am able to generate a Java Heap Space OutOfMemory exception with the following code on ColdFusion 9.01 (haven't tried earlier versions):

```
<cfset uuidGenerator = createObject("java", "java.util.UUID")>
<cfset transient = structNew()>
<cfloop from="1" to="100000" index="index">
    <cfset transient[uuidGenerator.randomUUID().toString()] = true>
</cfloop>
```

The code above uses the Java UUID class because its faster than ColdFusion's. The structure itself does not exist after the request (i.e. it's not in some persistent scope such as `application`).

As a test, I generate a heap dump just after initializing the server. Then I run this code several times and see the tenured generation fill through jConsole. After, I run another heap dump. Using Eclipse Memory Analysis Tool's Leak report I can see one large object rooted on `coldfusion.util.Key`.

I'm asking here in hopes others have hit similar problem, and if so, what they've done to work around it.

Comment: Not an answer, but I'm not sure java.util.UUID is all that much faster nowadays.  On CF8 it was, but native UUID creation is something like 1000x faster in 9+.

Comment: Can you reproduce the memory leak with native UUIDs or is it only with the Java UUIDs?

Comment: I also have to ask - are you seriously using a structure with 100K keys in it?

Comment: @CF Jedi Master: no, I am not using a structure with 100K keys in it. This test case refines a lot of trial an error reviewing heap dumps of putting an application under load and noticing this coldfusion.util.Key as the root.

Comment: @Todd Sharp: using `createUUID()` produces the same result.

Comment: Interesting. I compared his code to code that used createUUID(), and while his took around 200-400ms to complete, the createUUID version consistently took 10 seconds. So there are about 1000 UUIDs makde per second. Still fast - but not as fast as java.util.UUID().

Comment: I'd done some testing on this about 2 months ago and I could swear the difference was negligible - but that's staggering.  Still - I can't think of many times I'd need that damn many UUIDs.  @orangepips - at this point the only thing I can suggest is filing a bug.  Might also try this with a java hash map instead of a struct to see if the problem goes away.  If you're feeling pain from this then a hash map might be a temp workaround til Adobe can patch it.

Comment: @Todd Sharp: good suggest for the Java map, suspect this is what I may end up doing...

Comment: Let us know the results if you don't mind.  Also, don't forget to file a bug.

Comment: @Todd Sharp: bug #86893. ColdFusion bug tracker is God awful. I know they promised an update a month or two ago to something not Flash based, which is about 3 or 4 years too late.

Comment: Voted for that bug.  FWIW the bug tracker really doesn't bother me all that much.  Search could be improved, but I don't mind the Flex interface :)  Here's a direct link in case others want to vote: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=86893

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an ideal solution, but until Adobe fix the memory leak internally you can get access to the private member ConcurrentHasMap on the coldfusion.util.Key object and manually clear it.

We have setup a scheduled task to execute this nightly and then do a GC immediately afterwards.

Compile this into a JAR file and put it somewhere in your ColdFusion class path.

```
import coldfusion.util.Key;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

class KeyEx
{
    public KeyEx()
    {
    }

    public void resetCache(Object k)
    {
        try
        {
            Field f = Key.class.getDeclaredField("keys");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            ConcurrentHashMap chm = (ConcurrentHashMap)f.get(k);
            chm.clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ZOMG something went epically wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can simply instantiate the new KeyEx object in coldfusion and call resetCache passing in the coldfusion.util.Key singleton.

```
<cfset keys = createObject("java", "coldfusion.util.Key") />
<cfset x = createObject("java", "KeyEx").init() />
<cfset x.resetCache(keys) />
```

Comment: If you want any exception details, just remove the TRY/CATCH block and change the method declaration to: 'public void resetCache(Object k) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException'

Comment: +1 for a good idea on how to clear this up by mucking about with reflection APIs.

Answer (score 2):

These two example tests probably illustrate the problem a bit clearer:

**-- MemoryLeak.cfm**

```
<cfset transient = structNew() />
<cfset base = getTickCount() />
<cfloop from="1" to="10000" index="index">
  <cfset transient[hash("#base##index#")] = true >
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>
Done
</cfoutput>
```

**-- NoMemoryLeak.cfm**

```
 <cfset transient = structNew() />
 <cfloop from="1" to="10000" index="index">
 <cfset transient[hash("#index#")] = true >
 </cfloop>
 <cfoutput>
 Done
 </cfoutput>
```

Hit MemoryLeak.cfm on a CF 9.01+ box for 100 times and the memory leak is really obvious.  Restart JVM and hit NoMemoryLeak.cfm as many times as you want, and the OldGen won't even notice it. I got up to 500,000 times before giving up.

I can't see OrangePips original bug# in the CF bug-base (looks like all old bugs went in the upgrade?), so I created a new one https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3119991 status currently confirmed & ToFix.

Comment: It's the other way around - key value only retained if key size <40 bytes.  If if you do <cfset  transient[hash("#base##index#")&hash("#base##index#")]  = true >, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is what I ended up doing to track down the root cause. Heap dumps were showing me that `coldfusion.util.Key.keys` was holding on to *many* objects in a `ConcurrentHashMap` of type `coldfusion.util.Key` after I ran a load test for awhile. So I figured out which .jar contained the .class - /lib/cfusion.jar - and decompiled it to see the source. What I saw is that it holds onto these references in a static private field whose keys are *never* removed.

Basically this object gets created every time a key never used before is inserted into a structure. So it's called from all over any ColdFusion application. I believe the intent is to facilitate speedups around lookups, case insensitivity, and comparison.

Accepting then that I cannot change code to fix the issue, as I'm sure it would violate a license agreement when used in a production environment, I did change code to help me understand why so many objects were being created in the first place. I basically added the following to the constructor:

```
try {
  throw new RuntimeException();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Then I compiled and put the changed class into cfusion.jar.

Fortunately, the stack trace generated includes .cfm file names and line numbers. I started CF from a command line (i.e. jrun.exe -start coldfusion) so I could see what was going to  System.out easily and then kicked off my load test again. So the heuristic was finding what code was calling this *a lot* and potentially changing that.

This allowed me to quickly see a .cfm file that was being called with every request. So I can change that file to no longer create structure keys all the time and this has resulted in a much longer running VM. It doesn't fix the problem completely, but lowers memory consumption dramatically.

Comment: How about you use java.util.Hashtable instead of CF struct?  You can still access it, just make sure you pass the string in the right case.

Comment: @Henry: issue was I had no idea what structure, and there are many scattered about the application, was growing in such an unbounded fashion. Thus the stack trace. You are correct in as much that I could have also altered it to use a Map instead of reducing the number of entries generated.